# Sql is null in ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have class method to get posts but now sure how to resolve it.

So, somebody can set flag on post, but in meantime post doesn't have any flag :

```
Post.find(3).flag #nil
```

This is self method for getting posts :

```
 def self.for_review
   joins(:flag).where('need_approval = ? and question = ? and DATE(posts.created_at) =   ?', "true", "false", Time.now.to_date)
 .where('flags.need_check = ? or flags IS NULL', 'false')
 end
```

Problem is with second where condition

```
where('flags.need_check = ? or flag IS NULL', 'false')
```

Because flag is NULL doesn't work .

Is anybody knows what's problem ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joins` uses an `INNER JOIN` by default; this will only return posts that do have at least one flag. You need a `LEFT JOIN`. Assuming a `Post` has_many `flags`:

```
joins('LEFT JOIN flags ON posts.id = flags.post_id').where(...).where('flags.need_check = ? OR flags.id IS NULL', false)
```

Also drop the quotes around `true` and `false`, unless those fields are indeed strings with the literal values "true" and "false".

Answer (score 1):

THe problem is `joins(:flag)`. It defaults to inner join, so all the posts without flags will be rejected. You need `includes(:flag).references(:flag)` instead.

Also `flags IS NULL` makes no sense as there is no column called flags. Instead do `flags.id IS NULL`